# IE border-image and background-image box issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image, border-image

I have a Div with a tiled background-image and a border-image.  The border image is a transparent .png with corner designs, so the border box is about 90px thick all around.  IE starts the background-image inside the border box, where as FF, Chrome and Safari start the background-image at the outside edge of the border box.  In IE this cause the background-color(or background from the body) to show through the transparent .png border-image.  I've tried Background-clip and position to get IE to start the background image from the outside of the border box with no luck.

Anything I'm missing or suggestions?  Sample live right now @ [Sample](http://www.muldoons.net/index_01_2015.html)

```
 #Menu {
background-color: #DBD1AC;
background-image: url(images/texture_paper_tileable.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-clip: border-box;
background-position:0 0;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
height: auto;
width: 80%;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 91px 92px 90px;
-moz-border-image: url(images/menuBorderREDpaint.png) 91 92 90 stretch repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(images/menuBorderREDpaint.png) 91 92 90 stretch repeat;
-o-border-image: url(images/menuBorderREDpaint.png) 91 92 90 stretch repeat;
border-image:url(images/menuBorderREDpaint.png) 91 92 90 fill stretch repeat;
```

}

Parent would be body...

```
body {
font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
/*background-color: #42413C;*/
/*background-color: #2a1d0d; brown*/
background-color: #DBD1AC;
background-image: url(images/OldWood.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
color: #FFF;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround.
I have wrapped the menu div in another div and set the background image there. Then removed the background image from the menu div to allow it to show the wrapper div image behind it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "" ""><HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=edge" 
http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<style>
#Menu {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 91px 92px 90px;
-moz-border-image: url(menuBorderREDpaint.png) 91 92 90 stretch repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(menuBorderREDpaint.png) 91 92 90 stretch repeat;
-o-border-image: url(menuBorderREDpaint.png) 91 92 90 stretch repeat;
border-image:url(menuBorderREDpaint.png) 91 92 90 fill stretch repeat;
}
#MenuBackground{
background-image: url(texture_paper_tileable.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-clip: content-box;
background-position: 0 0;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
height: auto;
width: 80%;
}
</style>
<BODY>
<BR><BR>       
<div id="MenuBackground">
<DIV id="Menu">                                              
<BR><BR>
menu
<BR><BR>
</DIV>         
</div>     
<BR><BR>                    
</BODY></HTML>
```

I have put up there file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10815596/ieborderimage/index_01_2015.htm), I tested it on chrome and ie11.

Comment: Hi Jason, did this solve the problem you were having?

Comment: Yes, it did!! Thank you very much!! Sorry for the delay.